# Fluid height div INCLUDING margins

Tags: css, html, margin, fluid-layout

I have a div with blocks of text. Sometimes 4 paragraphs, sometimes 44.

I set the div height to height:100%:

The text within the div has a bottom margin of 1em, to make the paragraphs space nicely without me putting `<br>` or similar stuff in the code.

The problem is, the bottom margin pushes the div that comes after this one. It makes a 1em space because of the text bottom margin.

Is there a way to make the text div stretch to 100% INCLUDING the margin space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different box model with:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

It might be possible to accomplish what I think you are describing, you can read more [here](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).